# Scalable way to read large numbers of files with Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I’m writing a pipeline where I need to read the metadata files (500.000+ files) from the [Sentinel2 dataset](http://bigearth.net/) located on my Google Cloud Bucket  with [`apache_beam.io.ReadFromTextWithFilename`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html?highlight=readfromtextwithfilename#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromTextWithFilename).

It works fine on a small subset, but when I ran it on the full dataset it seems to block on `"Read Metadata" >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(f'gs://{BUCKET}/{DATA_FOLDER}/**/*metadata.json')`.

It dosen’t even show up in the Dataflow jobs list.

The pipeline looks like this:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    meta = (
        pipeline
        | "Read Metadata" >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(f'gs://{BUCKET}/{DATA_FOLDER}/**/*metadata.json')
        | "Extract metadata" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractMetaData())
    )
    table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
        datasetId="sentinel_2",
        tableId="image_labels",
    )
    (
        meta 
        | "Write To BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table_spec,
            schema=table_schema(),
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
        )
    )
```

I'm wondering:

1. **Is there a smarter way to read large numbers of files?**
2. **Will copying the metadata files into *one* folder be more performant?** (How much more does it cost to traverse sub-folders, as opposed to files in one folder)
3. **Is the way to go to match the file names first with [`apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchAll`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchAll)** and then read and extract in one or two following `ParDo`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was suffering from a case of [unwanted fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#preventing-fusion).

Drawing inspiration from the page about [file-processing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/) on the Apache Beam website, I tried to add a `Reshuffle` to the pipeline.

I also upgraded to a paid Google Cloud account,  thus getting higher quotas.
That resulted in Dataflow handling the job a lot better.

In fact Dataflow wanted to scale to 251 workers for my BiqQuery write job. At firste it didn't provision more workers, so I stopped the job and sat `--num_workers=NUM_WORKERS` and `--max_num_workers=NUM_WORKERS`, where `NUM_WORKERS` was the max qouta form my project. When running with those paramaters it scaled up automatically.

My final pipeline looks like this:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

          meta = (
              pipeline
              | MatchFiles(f'gs://{BUCKET}/{DATA_FOLDER}/*metadata.json')
              | ReadMatches()
              | beam.Reshuffle()
              | beam.Map(lambda x: (x.metadata.path, x.read_utf8()))
              | beam.ParDo(ExtractMetaData())
          )


          table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
              datasetId="sentinel_2",
              tableId="image_labels",
          )

          (
              meta 
              | "Write To BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                  table_spec,
                  schema=table_schema(),
                  write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
              )
          )
```

#### Appendix

I also got a hint that [`SplitableParDos`](https://beam.apache.org/blog/splittable-do-fn/) might be a solution, but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the pipeline running into Dataflow API limits when splitting the text source glob into a large number of sources.

Current solution is to use the transform [ReadAllFromText](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py) which should not run into this.

In the future we hope to update transform `ReadFromText` for this case as well by using the Splittable DoFn framework.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know!