# Same Apache beam code works in Direct Runner but not in Dataflow runner

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a piece of apache beam pipe code that reads from a file in the GCS bucket and prints it. It is working perfectly with the DirectRunner and prints the file output but with the Dataflow runner it is not printing anything no errors as well.

Do we need to do anything special/different for the Dataflow runner?

Code looks like this

```
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
  read_file_pipe = (
      p
      | "Create {}".format(file_name) >> beam.Create(["Start"])
      | "Read File {}".format(file_name)
      >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(file_path, skip_header_lines=1)
      | beam.Map(print)
  )

  p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

call stack is python3 Test_Pipe.py --region us-central1 --output_project= --runner=DataflowRunner --project=  --temp_location= --service_account_email= --experiments=use_network_tags=default-uscentral1 --subnetwork --no_use_public_ips

Comment: did you look in the "Worker logs" tab ? Did you change the level of severity of logs ? (INFO, DEBUG etc). Dis you try to use the `logging` package instead of `print`

Comment: If the job fails, it will definitely log errors in the Google Cloud console. But `print` will not write anything to the Dataflow logs. You need to set up `logging` in Python

Comment: Did you find anything related to this? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use `logging` instead of `print` to solve your issue, I added your code snippet with `logging` :

```py
import logging

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
  read_file_pipe = (
      p
      | "Create {}".format(file_name) >> beam.Create(["Start"])
      | "Read File {}".format(file_name)
      >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(file_path, skip_header_lines=1)
      | beam.Map(self.log_element)
  )

  p.run().wait_until_finish()

 def log_element(self, element):
     logging.info(element)

     return element
```

Comment: Did this address the issue ?

Comment: @HKS this solution solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was to change the approach of reading those files. I basically switched from `ReadFromTextWithFilename`  to `MatchFiles` (`apache_beam.io.fileio`).

For a reason that I still don't know `ReadFromTextWithFilename` hasn't the expected behaviour. Docs are also not clear about it.

My code looks like this now:

```
from apache_beam.io import fileio
import apache_beam as beam

def __expand_items(element):
    content = element.read_utf8()
    if content:
        items = content.splitlines()
        filename = element.metadata.path
        for item in items:
            yield (filename, item)

...
| "Match" >> fileio.MatchFiles(self.gcs_pattern, empty_match_treatment=fileio.EmptyMatchTreatment.ALLOW)
| "Read" >> fileio.ReadMatches()
| "Flatmap" >> beam.FlatMap(__expand_items)
| "Reshuffle -- avoid fusion" >> beam.Reshuffle()
```

My reference was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65852478/8684750).